# 70% credence region of a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ be a 2D random variable.

We want to find a threshold $t$ that defines an ellipsoid $S = \{(x,y) : f_X(x,y)>t\}$ such that $\int_S f_X = q = 0.7$.

How should I go about this?

My first attempt was tosolve it for the standard bivariate Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$.

Changing to polar coordinates

$$
x = r \cos \theta
$$

$$
y = r \sin \theta
$$

$\int_S f_X = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} f_X(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta) r dr d\theta = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} (2\pi)^{-1}e^{-r^2/2} r dr d\theta = \int_0^R e^{-r^2/2} r dr = [e^{-r^2/2}]_{r=0}^{r=R} =  e^{-R^2/2} - 1 = q = 0.7$

So $R = \sqrt {(-2\log {(1+q)})}$

But I am not 100% clear on how to change between the general case and the standard case.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: @kimchilover good catch! I was actually intending to use standard polar coordinates (I actually messed up the whole change of variables in the integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X, Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$ then $X^2+Y^2$ has the chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. (As the first sentence of the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution),

> In probability theory and statistics, the chi-square distribution (also chi-squared or $\chi^2$ -distribution) with $k$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of a sum of the squares of $k$ independent standard normal random variables

explains.)

Let $C$ be the 70% critical value for  this distribution, so $P(\chi_2^2\le C)=.7$.   This value tells you what you need: in the general case you have $f(x,y)=A\exp(-Q(x-\mu_x,y-\mu_y)/2)$ for some quadratic form $Q$; your region is than cut out by the inequality $Q(x-\mu_x,y-\mu_y)/2\le C$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you relate the $\chi^2$ to the bivariate gaussian. How do we jump from knowing that the critical value is $C$ to the inequality you suggest? Can you flesh that out?

Comment: I have supplied some of what I think you asked for.

Comment: So what I am confused about is how you relate the general bivariate gaussian to a sum of iid $N(0,1)$

Comment: An arbitrary multidimensional  gaussian vector can be represented as a linear transformation of a rotationally  symmetric gaussian: if $x\sim N(0,I)$ then $y=Ax\sim N(0,A^TA)$.  So if you know how to take the square roots of psd matrices, so given $\Sigma$ you can find $A$ with $\Sigma=A^TA$, you are done.